# Flutter AWS Cognito Token showing invalid signature

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am stared developing a flutter project with AWS Cognito login features. In flutter, AWS Cognito login was working fine and I am getting the access token but when checking that in API or JWT its shows the error "Invalid Signature".

[image]

I add the below code for the AWS Cognito login features. I have installed the `amplify_auth_cognito: '<1.0.0'` in pubspec.yaml file to create the AWS Cognito login features in the app. Login codes working fine and perfectly but the token which returns from that code shows "Invalid Signature".

```
  Future<String> _signIn(LoginData data) async {
try {
  SignInResult res = await Amplify.Auth.signIn(
    username: data.name,
    password: data.password,
  );
  final resp = await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
    options: CognitoSessionOptions(getAWSCredentials: true),
  );
  if (resp.isSignedIn) {
    final sess = resp as CognitoAuthSession;
    print("TOKEN FROM THE COGNITO: ${sess.userPoolTokens.accessToken}");
  }
  setState(() {
    isSignedIn = res.isSignedIn;
  });
  if (isSignedIn) {
    _btnController.success();
    AWSConfigurationHelper().getUserDetails();

    Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      _btnController.reset();
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, DeviceList.routeName);
    });
  }
} on AuthError catch (e) {
  Alert(
    context: context,
    type: AlertType.error,
    title: "Login Failed",
    desc: e.cause.toString(), //e.toString(),
  ).show();

  _btnController.error();

  Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    _btnController.reset();
  });

  print(e.cause);

  for (final exception in e.exceptionList) {
    print(exception.exception);
    print(exception.detail);
  }

  return 'Log In Error: ' + e.toString();
}}
```

My pubspec.yaml file screenshot was attached. In that file I am using `amplify_auth_cognito: '<1.0.0'` for the Cognito login.

[image]

I am new to this Flutter so I really need someone help to fix this problem. I have done the AWS Cognito Login features in iOS and web with the same AWS credentials but there I am not getting this type of "Invalid Signature" issue in the access token. Someone, please help me because I am not any good link where this type of issue has been discussed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The same problem here. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes, I got the solution its nothing but a log print error from visual studio. In visual studio log print only 1000 character so if you copy the AWS Cognito token from the log then token will show "Invalid Signature" issue. So you first check the length of the token. If token length more then 1000 character then print the other characters and concat them and you will get the correct token.